# How can I display a specific part of a page with color box without displaying the whole page in the pop up window?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

Ok , so I have a page that I am working on containing charts in the php code , but the same page also contains tables that are displayed...

How can I make it so I can create a link on the same page so that when users click on the link , I can have a pop up box only showing the charts of the page ..

```
<?php


echo" <a href="...."> click to see charts </a>";

chart code is below here //

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer following example and it works great

https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/example1/index.html